# Gson, auto-initialize and avoid null exceptions

Tags: java, initialization, gson

when deserializing a json into a `class Foo{int id; List<String> items; List<Long> dates;}` How could I auto initialize fields that are null after deserialization. Is there such a possiblity with Gson lib?

ex:

```
Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson("{\"id\":\"test\", \"items\":[1234, 1235, 1336]}", Foo.class)
foo.dates.size(); -> 0 and not null pointerException
```

I know I could do if (foo.attr == null) foo.attr = ...
but I'm looking for more generic code, without knowledge of Foo class
thx

*edit*: sorry just putting Getters in Foo is enough

---

closed

Comment: from where will you become the default values?

Comment: Try my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301036/gson-ignore-null-when-deserializing-object/56363895#56363895[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301036/gson-ignore-null-when-deserializing-object/56363895#56363895)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom deserializer.

Assuming your class is called `MyAwesomeClass`, you implement something like

```
MyAwesomeClassDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyAwesomeClass> {

@Override
public MyAwesomeClass deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) throws JsonParseException
{
    // TODO: Do your null-magic here

}
```

and register it with GSON, like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(MyAwesomeClass.class, new MyAwesomeClassDeserializer())
    .create();
```

Now, you just call a `fromJson(String, TypeToken)` method, to get your deserialized object.

```
MyAweSomeClass instance = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<MyAwesomeClass>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: I need to set the List<Long> to new ArrayList<Long>() if it's null,  how to convert json.getAsJsonArray() a JsonArray to a ArrayList<Long>?

Comment: Use the [`JsonArray#iterator()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#iterator%28%29) and just iterate over the `JsonArray` adding elements to the `List<>`.