# Gson ignore null when deserializing object

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I want to deserialize a json string that containts a null value in Java. I want to deserialize the object to a `Properties` object. The json string is something like:

```
{"prop1":null, "propr2":"fancy value"}
```

When I deserialize using

```
String json = //
new Gson().fromJson(json, Properties.class);
```

I get a null pointer exception because of the `Hastable` that into the `Properties` object. How can I instruct Gson to ignore deserialization of null values?

Comment: I am having the same problem, even with a custom deserializer.  I can and do check for nulls but it s a lot of checks. Anything in the api that you can use to check if a property exists and that the value is non null?

Comment: Sometimes I think that would be simpler to provide an extension of Properties.

Comment: @mat_boy would you mind changing the title to something like "Gson ignore null values when deserializing Properties object"? Since that appears to be what your question is about. Ignoring `null` values in general is probably not easily or at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that Gson's default adapter tries to put `null` into the `Properties`, which is forbidden.

To solve this, you could write your own [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) for `Properties`. You would then have to create Gson instances using a `GsonBuilder` on which you [registered](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeAdapter(java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.Object)) that type adapter.

The following shows how such an adapter could look. It is slightly more strict in that it prevents non-String keys and values during serialization (which Gson's default adapter does not) since they would cause issues during deserialization. You could however replace that and delegate serialization to Gson's adapter by using [Gson.getDelegateAdapter​](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html#getDelegateAdapter(com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory,com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken)).

```
private static final TypeAdapter<Properties> PROPERTIES_ADAPTER = new TypeAdapter<Properties>() {
    @Override
    public Properties read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        in.beginObject();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String name = in.nextName();
            JsonToken peeked = in.peek();

            // Ignore null values
            if (peeked == JsonToken.NULL) {
                in.nextNull();
                continue;
            }
            // Allow Json boolean
            else if (peeked == JsonToken.BOOLEAN) {
                properties.setProperty(name, Boolean.toString(in.nextBoolean()));
            }
            // Expect string or number
            else {
                properties.setProperty(name, in.nextString());
            }
        }

        in.endObject();
        return properties;
    }

    private String asString(Object obj) {
        if (obj.getClass() != String.class) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Properties contains non-String object " + obj);
        }
        return (String) obj;
    }

    /*
     * Could also delegate to Gson's implementation for serialization.
     * However, that would not fail if the Properties contains non-String values,
     * which would then cause issues when deserializing the Json again. 
     */
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Properties properties) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
            // Make sure that key is a String, otherwise properties
            // cannot be deserialized again
            out.name(asString(entry.getKey()));

            Object value = entry.getValue();
            // Be lenient and allow Numbers and Booleans as values
            if (value instanceof Number) {
                out.value((Number) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
                out.value((Boolean) value);
            } else {
                // Require that value is a String
                out.value(asString(value));
            }
        }

        out.endObject();
    }

}.nullSafe(); // Handle null Properties, e.g. `Properties props = null`

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        // Register the custom type adapter
        .registerTypeAdapter(Properties.class, PROPERTIES_ADAPTER)
        .create();

    String json = "{\"prop1\":true, \"prop2\":\"text\", \"prop3\":null}";
    Properties deserialized = gson.fromJson(json, Properties.class); 
    System.out.println("Deserialized: " + deserialized);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("prop", "text");
    // Discouraged to put non-Strings, but type adapter supports these
    properties.put("boolean", true);
    properties.put("number", 1234);
    System.out.println("Serialized: " + gson.toJson(properties));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We have this solution:

**1. All of your data classes need to extends abstract class**

```
abstract class PoJoClass
```

**2. Create this safe deserializer to delete nulls from JSON**

```
class SafeDeserializer<T : PoJoClass>(private val gson: Gson) :JsonDeserializer<T> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): T {

        val jsonObject = json as JsonObject
        removeNullsFromJson(jsonObject)
        return gson.fromJson(jsonObject, typeOfT)
    }

    private fun removeNullsFromJson(jsonObject: JsonObject) {
        val iterator = jsonObject.keySet().iterator()

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            val key = iterator.next()
            when(val json = jsonObject[key]){
                is JsonObject -> removeNullsFromJson(json)
                is JsonNull -> iterator.remove()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3. And register it in your GSON instance**

```
val gson = Gson().newBuilder()
                .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(PoJoClass::class.java, SafeDeserializer<PoJoClass>(Gson()))
                .create()
```

Answer (score -7):

See http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();`

Comment: This is for serialization. I need to deserialize

Comment: I saw that it's for serialization, but I guess deserialize will also work. Assuming gson produces something it could deserialize again.