# Gson deserialize returning all null values [Java]

Tags: java, json, serialization, null, gson

My response Json format looks like this

```
[
  {
    "cpm": "$33.00",
    "id": 13125,
    "name": "zemindary, eichwaldite",
    "startDate": "2018-01-04"
  },
  {
    "cpm": "$9.00",
    "id": 652,
    "name": "polyandrian self-exciter",
    "startDate": "2018-01-04"
  }
]
```

However when I use Gson to deserialize my data, all the values are null

Here is my code to read and deserialize the JSON into my Object

```
Gson g = new Gson();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ) {
    content.append(inputLine);
}
Campaigns[] newCamp = g.fromJson(content.toString(), Campaigns[].class);
for (int i = 0; i < newCamp.length; i++) {
    Document doc = Document.createDocument("id", newCamp[i].getId())
        .put("cpm", newCamp[i].getCpm())
        .put("name", newCamp[i].getName())
        .put("startDate", newCamp[i].getStartDate());
    collection.insert(doc);
    System.out.println(doc);
}
```

Here is my data model:
    public class Campaigns {

```
public String startDate;
public String cpm;
public int id;
public String name;

public Campaigns () {

}

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getCpm() {
    return cpm;
}
public void setCpm(String cpm) {
    this.cpm = cpm;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Here is what I'm currently getting when printing out the data model

> {id=14789, cpm=null, name=null, startDate=null, _id=20548426011802, _revision=1, _modified=1523897108160}

Comment: Please paste only the relevant code, rather than using screenshots.

Comment: @ReadyPlayer2 Updated with my code

Comment: Since your code is not complete can you try to print the `content.toString()` and confirm that the result is equals to your response?

Comment: @BilalELCHAMI Wow its always the simple things. I realized i was passing in the wrong API call for a different data model...

Comment: I'm glad it helped ^^ Best of luck.

Comment: Try to see my answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301036/gson-ignore-null-when-deserializing-object/56363895#56363895](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301036/gson-ignore-null-when-deserializing-object/56363895#56363895)