# When deserialising an object using 'fromJson', Gson makes empty array 'null'

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

This is how I build my Gson: `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();`

This is how I create objects from Json:

```
JsonObject obj = gson.fromJson(line, JsonObject.class); //JsonObject allows us to retrieve information by name

Class<? extends Tile> resultClass = (Class<? extends Tile>) Class.forName(obj.get("className").getAsString()); //Get the class of the tile we are currently processing
newTile = resultClass.cast(gson.fromJson(line, resultClass)); //Cast the new tile to the correct class
```

I've debugged this code and it seems to work fine (returns an object with the same values as in the json). However, when I am trying to access an empty array (which is not listed in the json) in the super-superclass of the object, the array is 'null'. The array is initiated like this:

`private ArrayList<Entity> elements = new ArrayList<Entity>();`

So everytime the object is created the normal way, the array is initiated, but when creating it with Gson, the array is null.

Does Gson not initialize empty arrays? Do I have to include the empty array in the Json in order for it to be initialized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11407541/2920722

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Gson encounters a variable which doesn't have a field in the json file, then it will automatically be set to null, instead of it's default value.
[Source](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/513)

I guess I will just have to either save every variable to a field, or to manually create the object and manually apply the relevant fields.